The possible number of equivalence classes for the invariants of two congruent matrices
Hi i was doing the exercize 26 section 6.8 of Linear Algebra Friedberg et al., the exercize says: prove that the number of possible equivalence classes between two congruent matrix (so the number of combination of negative, positive and 0 eigenvalues) is $\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{2}$, where $n$ is the dimension of the square matrix ($n x n$). I tried to prove it like this, but I ended up in a different formula. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ suppose $rank(A) = k, \space 0\leq k \leq n$, for this rank there will be $k+1$ possible equivalence classe (bacause there are 0 positive eigenvalues and k negative, 1 positive and k-1 negative and so on, and a fixed number of 0'), so the totale number of possibilities is just $$\sum_{k=0}^n( k+1) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1) = 1 +n+\sum_{k=1}^nk = 1+n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{2+2n+n^2-n}{2}=\frac{2+n+n^2}{2}$$

Both your answer and the author’s answer are wrong.
Your answer is wrong because $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ is equal to $\frac{n(n\color{red}{+}1)}{2}$, not $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
The answer in the book has probably a typo. If the author really meant $\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{2}$, I think he would have written $\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}$ instead.
Anyway, the correct answer is the number of ways to partition $n$ undistinguishable objects into three distinguishable classes. Using the balls-and-sticks formula, the answer should be $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$.

sorry that was my typo, the second one is a 2
